# SNMP-Linux-Load-Average Centreon Arguments

Tags: snmp, nagios

i am configuring Centreon, and i want to monitor the Load Average through a Service Template: "SNMP-Linux-Load-Average", though i have three arguments for warning and critical.

The example show for warning 4,3,2 and for critical 6,5,4, what these numbers mean?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/209566/what-warning-and-critical-values-to-use-for-check-load

Answer (score 1):

These No shows the severity of the alert. The numbers shows the load balancing severity.

this can be help full to you. to understand and this question should be asked in serverfault.com you will get exact answer

https://serverfault.com/questions/209566/what-warning-and-critical-values-to-use-for-check-load